# How do I make sure all values in an array contain a number and underscore?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, loops, foreach

I do not have access to the form so I cannot use client side validation. I need to use PHP code to check each value in an array and make sure each entry is in a certain format. All of the entries needs to start with a number (e.g., 1, 04, 10, 55, 9069) followed by an underscore and than more alphanumeric.

Examples of valid entries:

5_lAb-3004-012

015_36hl_Dm

99_h3-mm-01

1_sdfd

Examples of invalid entries:

kk_12-04o

12-63-ll

_he-666-aa

0_jjdjd

So what is the code to check an array and echo an error if any of the entries/values are not of the correct format?

Code I've tried:

```
    // START - My add-on for checking for an underscore in the parts field.
            $parts = $hForm->getValue("parts");

            if (is_array($parts) && !empty($parts)) {
                $partsim=implode(" ",$parts);
                if (!preg_match('/_/', $partsim)) {
                $hForm->setError("parts", "Missing Qty!");
                }
            }
// END - My add-on for checking for an underscore in the parts field.
```

The code above only checks the entire array for an underscore. I need the code to check each value in the array and if the regex I decribed is found in any of the array values, echo an error.

Comment: This isn't a code-delivery platform. How would you do it on the client side? What have you tried? This screams regex.

Comment: @SBI I was referring to using JavaScript on the form page for validation before the form is processed by PHP when I mentioned clientside. I realize regex is needed but everything I tried failed. I added what I have so far but it's not what I need. I Googled for several hours but still can't put the pieces together :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that contributed :-)

The example regex's that were provided gave me a good starting point but they do not work for the example valid/invalid entries I listed in my original post. Also, no one provided any info about how to check each value in an array.

Anyway, below is the code I came up with that works:

```
// START - My add-on that checks for qty prefix in the parts field.
$parts = $hForm->getValue("parts");
if (is_array($parts) && !empty($parts)) {
    $missingQty = false;
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (!preg_match("/^\d+_+.*$/", $part)) {
            $missingQty = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($missingQty) {
        $hForm->setError("parts", "Missing Qty!");
    }
}
// END - My add-on that checks for qty prefix in the parts field.
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by SBI, it screams regex.

You'll need to use:

```
preg_match ("/^\d+_\w+$/", $array_string_element)
```

Explanation:

> Starts with a number

```
^\d+
```

> Followed by underscore

```
_
```

> Then more Alphanumerics

```
\w+$
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for explain each part.